# Stop the infinite loop after refresh token api is called in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, https, axios

I have created my custom Axios service, and everything is working fine but sometimes after the refresh token API is called the other API gets stuck in a loop.

My Axios service code -

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { getToken } from '../../../utils/constant_data';
import { refreshAccessToken } from '../../../saga/api/user.api';
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';
import { SERVICE_URL } from '../../../constants';

const mainBackendInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: SERVICE_URL
});

export const mainBackendInstanceWithoutToken = axios.create({
  baseURL: SERVICE_URL,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'App-Version-Code': 87,
    'Client-Platform': 'web'
  }
});

const mainBackendRequestInterceptor = (config) => {
  config.headers = {
    ...config.headers,
    Authorization: getToken(),
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'App-Version-Code': 87,
    'Client-Platform': 'web',
    'Company-Id': +localStorage.getItem('company_id')
  };
  return config;
};

const mainBackendResponseInterceptor = (response) => {
  return response;
};

const mainBackendResponseErrorInterceptor = async (error) => {
  const originalRequest = error.config;
  if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
    originalRequest._retry = true;
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
    if (refreshToken) {
      await refreshAccessToken();
      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
      originalRequest.headers = {
        ...originalRequest.headers,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      };
    }
    return mainBackendInstance(originalRequest);
  } else {
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload();
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
};

axiosRetry(mainBackendInstance, {
  retries: 2,
  retryCondition: (error) => {
    return error.response.status === 500;
  }
});

mainBackendInstance.interceptors.request.use(mainBackendRequestInterceptor);
mainBackendInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  mainBackendResponseInterceptor,
  mainBackendResponseErrorInterceptor
);

const mainBackendAxiosService = {
  get: (url, params) => mainBackendInstance.get(url, { params }),
  post: (url, data, config) =>
    mainBackendInstance.post(url, data, {
      headers: config?.headers,
      params: config?.params
    }),
  put: (url, data, config) =>
    mainBackendInstance.put(url, data, {
      headers: config?.headers,
      params: config?.params
    }),
  patch: (url, data) => mainBackendInstance.patch(url, data),
  delete: (url, data) => mainBackendInstance.delete(url, data)
};

export default mainBackendAxiosService;
```

My issue was resolved by using the **_retry** flag but is there any other way to do it? This seems like a quick fix but a permanent solution.